# Rails 4 / Rack disregarding _method override parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, url-routing, rack

I have a Rails 4 application with a shallow nested route:

```
  resources :funds do
    resources :fund_mappings, shallow: true
  end
```

I understand that `PATCH /fund_mappings/(:id)` should match `FundMappingController#update` because the route is shallow (so only the routes for `new` and `create` will actually contain `/fund/` at the beginning). Indeed, this route is listed in the output of `rake:routes`:

```
PATCH   /fund_mappings/:id(.:format)    fund_mappings#update
```

Of course browsers don't really work with PUT, PATCH or DELETE so there's a hack in Rack (I believe) which should swap out the HTTP method for the contents of the `_method` HTTP parameter.

So when I went to update a record and got this error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/fund_mappings/1"
```

I thought that the form I was submitting didn't have the `_method` field with the value `patch`. So I inspected the form, and there was such a field with that value. Also, the Rails error page indicated that it came through fine:

```
{
 "utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"stuff",
 "fund_mapping"=> {
   "key"=>"asdf",
   "source_id"=>"1"
 },
 "commit"=>"Save"
}
```

So why is Rails (or Rack) thinking that this is a POST request?

Comment: Can you post the `form` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that including the gem `rails-api` in my Gemfile caused this. I have an API part of my application, and a human UI part, so I had created an `ApiController` which inherited from `ActionController::API` (from the gem) for the API stuff. Separately, I had an `ApplicationController`which inherited from `ActionController::Base` just like normal for the human UI stuff. I thought that the `rails-api` related stuff would be confined to the `ApiController` -- turns out that's wrong.

`rails-api` and `rails` aren't meant to coexist, and it breaks many things if you try. However if you set your application's `config.api_only = false` (by default, it's true), then it stops breaking this part.

The combination of these two lines in `rails-api` was causing this issue:

[setting config.api_only = true](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/master/lib/rails-api/application.rb#L37)

[don't include Rack::MethodOverride in the middleware stack for the application if config.api_only = true](https://github.com/rails-api/rails-api/blob/master/lib/rails-api/application/default_rails_four_middleware_stack.rb#L33)